# Passing arguments of unknown types

Tags: c#, methods

How can I pass Arguments of **unknown types** in an Action delegate?

```
Button b1 = new Button("HI!", Class.method);
```

in the class:

```
Action doAction;
string text;

public Button(string Message, Action func)
    {
        text = Message;
        doAction = func;
    }

public void Clicked()
    {
        doAction();
    }
```

I want to achieve that I can pass arguments in the function when adding a Button:

```
Button b2 = new Button("HI!", Class.method(unknown_parameter));
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I've heard of something with `Action<T>` but it's really unclear to me.

Comment: Either use type `Object`, `dynamic` or `generics`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses in `Class.method(unknown_parameter)` will try to call the function, so you cannot pass parameters like that. Instead, you have to pass the parameters as well, and execute the method within the function.

You could do that for example with generics:

```
class Button<T>
{
    public Button (string message, Action<T> func, T param)
    {
        func(param); // calls the method
    }
}

new Button<string>("foo", Class.method, "bar");
```

You could also pass in a lambda expression which calls the method:

```
class Button
{
    public Button (string message, Action func)
    {
        func(); // calls the function
    }
}

new Button("foo", () => Class.method("bar"));
```

Comment: Thanks.
Your second solution seems to be the better choice here.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know at all what the type is going to be, you could use "Action<object>" in which case the code would look like this:

```
public Button(string Message, Action<object> func)
{
    text = Message;
    doAction = func;
}

public void Clicked(object o)
{
    doAction(o);
}
```

But... the challenge is going to be how to deal with the unknown type inside "doAction". There are various ways around that problem, but to really be able to recommend what to do I think we'd need to see some examples of where the unknown parameter is coming from. Typically we have **some** idea of what the possible types are doing to be.